# Error writing /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-4.0.repo : Permission Denied

Tags: mongodb, git, amazon-web-services

I am trying to install mongodb on my amazon linux 2 server by following the documentation [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/) but when I am trying to save the repo file it shows the following error

> Error writing /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-4.0.repo: Permission Denied

The repo file contents are:

> [mongodb-org-4.0]
>
> name=MongoDB Repository
>
> baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2/mongodb-org/4.0/x86_64/
>
> gpgcheck=1
>
> enabled=1
>
> gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.0.asc

The error is displayed when I try to save my file. 
How can I resolve this error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: write sudo before execute command

Answer (score 3):

Are you logged in as ec2-user?  If so, use sudo to edit the file.

If you're setting up several things that require root access, try:
 sudo su -

then make all the changes and when your finished: exit

then you'll be back on the ec2-user